# Form submit not receveing multiple html select

Tags: python, html, django, forms, post

I have a little form with 2 fields, a hidden and a multiple select. When I submit the form, I receive the hidden field in the django views.py file, but the multiple select doesn't appear; it's like it was never there. What is the problem?

There is the form's code:

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/admin/grupos/configuracao/broadcast/post/" style="margin:0;" id="form_grupo">
        <table cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px; border:2px solid #ccc;">
            <tbody>

                    <tr><td width="50%"><input  onclick="remove_grupo()"  type="button" value="Remover do Grupo" style="float:left; margin-top:205px;"></td><td>

                   <select id="select-to" name="unidades"  style="width:360px;height:500px;" multiple="multiple">
                {% ifnotequal numero_unidades 0 %}
            {% for unidade in unidades %}
                     <option value="{{ unidade.relacao.id }}">
                        {{ unidade.desc }}
                     </option>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endifnotequal %}
        </select>   
        <input type="hidden" name="grupo_id" id="grupo_id" value="{{ grupo.id }}">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

My view:

```
def Salvar_Configuracao_Grupo_UR( request ):

    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_superuser:

        Grupo_EPR.objects.filter( grupo = request.POST['grupo_id'] ).delete()
        grupo = Grupo.objects.filter( id = request.POST['grupo_id'] )[0]
        unidades = request.POST.getlist('unidades')

        for unidade in unidades:
            grupo_epr = Grupo_EPR()
            grupo_epr.relacao = unidade
            grupo_epr.grupo = grupo
            grupo_epr.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/admin/grupos/configuracao/broadcast/0')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')
```

Comment: Can you give your view ?

Comment: @Zulu i've edited the question with the view

Comment: Are you actually selecting any items in the select?

Comment: Can you tell where the multiple select doesn't appear ? Did you test to print request.POST (or use debug_toolbar) ?

Comment: you're right @Quentin ... i wasn't selecting anything when form submits... how can i select all options just before submitting? it's because i am using this as a many to many form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view, use `request.GET.getlist()` or `request.POST.getlist()` to get a list of values from several inputs with same name.

Comment: i've already did that. but it doesn't work. It's like django request doesn't recognize the <select multiple>

Comment: i wasn't selecting anything when form submits... it's because i am using this as a many to many form

Comment: lifesaver in 2021